# setup.py needs version 3 when my default is version 2 of python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04

```
v = sys.version_info
  if v[:2] < (3,3):
    error = "ERROR: Jupyter Hub requires Python version 3.3 or above."
    print(error, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)
```

The above code is from setup.py of a repository. When I try running

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I get an error saying I require version 3.3 and above.

Also when I run

```
python --version
```

I get Python 2.7.6

And when I run

```
python3 -V
```

I get Python 3.4.3

So, I tried going to the ./bashrc file (following this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu) and setting

```
alias python=python3
```

but it didn't work. And I don't have a ~/.bash_aliases file

I'm very unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: `pip3` or `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: @JoshLee Thanks! It worked!